# Clarify meaning of "families $G$ of subsets of $X$" in linked answer

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

The second line of [**this answer**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1846902/344247) states

> The elements of the poset $Z$ are families $G$ of subsets of $X$, that
>   contain $F$ (the fixed $F$ we start out with, and which has the FIP),
>   so we have $F \subseteq G$ for all $G \in Z$, and such that $G$ has
>   the FIP

Question: **I am confused about the fact that we have $F\subseteq G$**, because $G$ is a family of subsets of $X$, which I think of as a *function*, while $F$ is just some subset of $X$.

That is, in few words, how can a set be a subset of a function (I realize a function is a set, but it is a set of ordered pairs. Here $F$ is not a set of ordered pairs)

---

**Question in More Detail**

Specifically, at [this question ("What is the difference between a family and a set")](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/35468/344247) the answer states that

> Strictly speaking, a family is a *function* $I \to U$, where $I$ is an
>   index set and $U$ is a universe that contains the members of the
>   family.

Using the notation of the first block quotations, then the poset $Z$ should consist of functions $G:I\to X$, but since a function is really a collection of ordered pairs, then we can write $G=\{(i,x)\big\vert i\in I,\  x\in X\}$ (**note I am slightly abusing notation in that every element of "$X$" in this definition contains $F$**)

**I am then unclear about how the claim $F\subseteq G$ can hold**, given than $G$ is a set of ordered pairs -- albeit of which the second part contains $F$ -- while $F$ does not have ordered pairs (that is, these seem like different objects to me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second answer you linked is describing the term "family" as used in the article linked in its question.  This is not the only possible meaning of "family"; another is that a family is just a set.  That is the meaning being used in the first answer you linked: "$G$ is a family of subsets of $X$" just means "$G$ is a set of subsets of $X$".

Comment: That clarifies things (although then I prefer the phrasing "G is a set of subsets of X" over "G is a family of subsets of X"). Thank you